# polynomial multiplication with integer polynomial result

Tags: polynomials, polynomial-rings, integer-rings

`A(z)`, `B(s)`, `D(s)` are polynomials.
`A(s)` is a polynomial on top of the integers, and `D(s)` is a monic polynomial not necessarily with integer coefficients.
`B(s)` is not necessarily monic.
I have:

```
A(s) = B(s)D(s)
```

Does that imply `B(s)` is on top of the integers? if so, how do I prove it?

Comment: What you call "on top of the integers" means with polynomial coefficient? If so, then yes, this result holds. Look at the euclidean division algorithm for polynomial, and notice that as long as you divide by a polynomial whose leading coefficient is invertible, then the algorithm works in any ring.

Comment: D(s) is not necessarily with integer coefficients. Does the proof still holds?

Comment: The same proof does not hold in that case. If $B$ is monic as well (i.e $A$ is monic), then the fact remains true, by what is called "Gauss Lemma for polynomials", but it's a bit more complicated, you should look it up.